# postman sending string of integers and splitting and converting them into an array in the server

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok I have gone through other questions but no one had this issue.
The problem is when I send a string as **rate : "10,10,10,10"** in postman.
In my server

```
var arr = [];
console.log(req.body.rate.split(',')); // '"10',10,'10','10','10"'
arr = req.body.rate.split(',').map(function(i){
    return parseInt(i, 10); // [Nan, 10, 10, 10, Nan]
})
```

what I expect is [10, 10, 10, 10];

Also tried parseInt which doesnot work.
Well  "" is causing the problem. I don't want to use some splice and all as the lenght of the string is not fixed.

Comment: Looks like you're sending `'"10,10,10,10"'` (with quotation marks), but expecting `'10,10,10,10'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete any quote from the string before casting it to integer.

```
arr = req.body.rate.split(',').map(function(i){
    return parseInt(i.replace('"', '').replace("'", ''));
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: worked well but what happened here, can you tell me please . (i.replace('"', '').replace("'", ''));

Comment: i know what replace function does  so just guessing you replaced " " to blank space ' ' and again ' ' to blank space\

Comment: [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) replaces the quotes with empty string. thus deletes them. Notes that `"'"` is a single quote string and `'"'` is a double quote string.